# Is there no way to hide save option on pdf pop up

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net

I have a pdf that Iam showing through embed tag. while showing pdf there comes a pop up to save it, print it ..I could disable print and content copying by document properties .But how could I disable save option? It seems this problem cant get solved.Is there a way to disable it through javascript or css? Please help.I have used following code but it also don't work after postback

```
string embed = "<object data=\"{0}{1}#toolbar=0&navpanes=0\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"855px\" style='padding-left:20px;' height=\"700px\">";
embed += "</object>";
ltEmbed.Text = string.Format(embed, ResolveUrl("~/admin/ShowPdf.ashx?Id=1&FilePath="), strFilePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this may b this help you

```
ResolveUrl("~/admin/ShowPdf.ashx?Id=1&FilePath="), strFilePath
```